# Score based on string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field say "testField", where in there can be numerous string values like. I need to boost the score whenever the value in the field is a particular string,say for example "testValue". How can I do this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `function_score`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "testField": "testValue"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```